# Invalid encoding: ISO-8859-1

Tags: debian, apache-httpd

I tried to use the `Stripe webhook`, but I have an error on my endpoint: `Invalid encoding: ISO-8859-1`.

I use `Apache2` with Debian.

I tried to add the following (which didn't work):

- `IndexOptions +Charset=UTF-8` into my `.htaccess`
- `AddDefaultCharset utf-8` into `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf`
- `AddDefaultCharset utf-8` into `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`
- `AddDefaultCharset utf-8` into `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/mydomain.com.conf`
- `AddDefaultCharset utf-8` into `/etc/apache2/conf-enabled/charset.conf`

I restarted `Apache2` between each test.

EDIT: I checked my `php.ini` and [default_charset](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.default-charset)  = `UTF-8`.
I'm using Symfony Framework.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Symfony, but check the encoding of your files first, then check the 'Content-Type' response header (web developer tools of your browser). In Symfony, test the output of [Kernel.getCharset()](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/kernel.html#charset) (probably deprecated if 
you have a different version) and [Response.getCharset()](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation.html#response) (defaults to UTF-8 if not set).

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Answer (score 1):

The `AddDefaultCharset` directive does not change the encoding of your content, it only changes the response header (e.g. `Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8`).
Generally it should not be needed if your HTML has a meta tag like `<meta charset="utf-8">` and the content actually *is* encoded in UTF-8.

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#adddefaultcharset

> This directive specifies a default value for the media type charset parameter (the name of a character encoding) to be added to a response if and only if the response's content-type is either `text/plain` or `text/html`. This should override any charset specified in the body of the response via a `META` element, though the exact behavior is often dependent on the user's client configuration. A setting of `AddDefaultCharset Off` disables this functionality. `AddDefaultCharset On` enables a default charset of `iso-8859-1`.
>   ...

and furthermore...

> `AddDefaultCharset` should only be used when all of the text resources to which it applies are known to be in that character encoding and it is too inconvenient to label their charset individually.

You should check the encoding of your content. If you're using PHP, check the setting of [default_charset](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.default-charset) in your `php.ini`.

You can run the `file` to command to get a clue of your files' encodings.

Example:

```
$ file *.html
iso.html:  HTML document, ISO-8859 text
utf8.html: HTML document, UTF-8 Unicode text
```